# Add an application deadline field to Careers job listings

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Top of the careers side-bar for me is [this advert](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/40523/web-developer-thames-valley-police):

> Web Developer
>   Thames Valley Police
>   Kidlington, United Kingdom

but if you click through it says:

> The closing date for enquiries and receipt of completed applications is Friday 27th September 2013.

which was last week. Now on one hand they've paid for a 30-day listing so there's some small value continuing to show it (for brand awareness, etc. I suppose) but on the other hand it's useless as a job listing.

There's currently no 'application deadline' field on the [job listing form](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/post?marketId=3&c=1). Might it be worth adding one so employers have the option of expiring the listing early?